# Any set $A\subseteq E$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}^-$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading Borell's *Lecture Notes in Measure Theory* and am confused on pg.26. The link to the paper is [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~borell/MeasureTheory.pdf).

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a positive measure space, and $\mathcal{M}^-$ be the class of $E\subseteq X$ such that there exist sets $A, B\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $A\subseteq E\subseteq B$ and $B\backslash A\in\mathcal{Z}_\mu$, where $\mathcal{Z}_\mu$ is the null set. Let $\bar{\mu}$ be the function such that $\bar{\mu}(E) = \mu(A)$, where $A\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $A\subseteq E$.

I've confirmed that $\mathcal{M}^-$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and that $\bar{\mu}$ is a positive measure on $\mathcal{M}^-$.

However, the sentence "if $E\in\mathcal{Z}_\mu$ the definition of $\bar{\mu}$ shows that any set $A\subseteq E$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}^-$" gets me. Here, $A$ is a subset of $X$, but may not necessarily be a member of $\mathcal{M}$. Therefore, it is not necessarily a member of $\mathcal{M}^-$, so this conclusion cannot be reached. All previous statements concerning some $A\subseteq E$ rests on the assumption that $A\in\mathcal{M}$.

With which fact does this statement hold? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $A$ in your quote is not required to belong to $\mathcal{M}$. I think that you are mixing notations, because both $A$'s in your text (in your second paragraph and in the quote in the fourth) refer to different sets.

The quoted statement is a consequence of $\emptyset \subset A\subset E$ and that $E\setminus \emptyset \in\mathcal{Z}_\mu $ whenever $E\in \mathcal{Z}_\mu $.

Comment: I see! Since $E\in\mathcal{Z}_\mu$, then $E\in\mathcal{M}$. So if $A\subset E$, then $A\subset X$, and there exists members $\emptyset, E\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $\emptyset\subset A\subset E$, and since $E\backslash\emptyset = E\in\mathcal{Z}_\mu$, then $A\in\mathcal{M}^-$.

Comment: @dTdt exactly, you get it